Flagging incomprehensible answers, got disputed
Recently, I flagged two answers by the same user as not an answer, because I cannot see any meaning out of them (and I highly doubt anyone will do). 

An answer to: When not to use 厕所 when asking for the toilet?
An answer to: What does 狗吃连帮 mean?

But to my surprise, both of them got "disputed" by the reviewer. I wanted to know the reason behind this, so if I really flagged them incorrectly, I'd not make the same mistake again next time. Thanks.

You didn't do anything wrong, both those answers are unclear, particularly the second one. Both times, your flag put the answer in the review queue. Both times, some people agreed with you and some didn't, so the answer didn't get deleted.
It looks to me like the user was trying to be helpful in both cases, and he just had trouble phrasing it clearly in English. That's a common problem on language learning sites, so I try to look at what the user intended. If I think they're being intentionally unhelpful, I will delete the post. Otherwise, I'll leave it alone, improve it with an edit, or add a friendly comment.
Thanks for helping to improve our community.
